# Set initial id of has_one association on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First attempt at Rails associations and I am failing to get the following code working. My goal is to have the report status initially set to record id 1. Record 1 in the status table is 'OPEN'. I will later change this to 2 so it is 'CLOSED'.

Models are set as follows;

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reports
end
```

Report controller has the following code which I can not get working;

```
  def create
    @report = Report.new(report_params)
    @report.create_status(1)

    if @report.save
      redirect_to @report
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I know the problem is with the `@report.create_status(1)` however I am not able to find any clarity on the interwebs. I am clearly not looking in the right place.

Additionally, my routes.rb is configured as below, but I am not sure if this is the most correct way;

```
  resources :reports do
    resources :comments
    resource :status
  end
```

**UandI's answer correct my issues. For info, I was confused with how I had my has_one and belongs_to associations configured. I had them reversed and they should be as follows in my situation;**

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :reports
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the status you want to assign is status 'OPEN' and it's column name is `column_name`

Replace the following line:

```
@report.create_status(1)
```

with this

```
@report.status = Status.find_by_column_name('OPEN')
```

Here in above line replace the `column_name` with the status's column's name of `OPEN`

E.G. if your column's name is status_name then the line would become `@report.status = Status.find_by_status_name('OPEN')`